# Why can't I see my button on my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning C#, and am currently studying windows forms (because I would like to plot things).

I'm following an online tutorial, and have written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Exercise : Form
{
    private Button btnSubmit;

    public Exercise()
    {
        btnSubmit = new Button();
        Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
    }
}

public class program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        Application.Run();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This should define a button on my form, according to the Introduction of [this tutorial](http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/Lesson03.htm), but when I right click and choose "View Designer", there's no button on the form, and when I try to run it, nothing pops up.

As far as I can tell, it is the Controls.Add method that should [make a visual representation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the button, but I don't see it. Where did it go?

If it matters, I started the project by selecting an empty project, making it a windows form project and by adding a class to it.

Comment: Adding buttons in code won't add it to the designer.  It would only show up during runtime.

Comment: You should really use the designer instead of manually coding your UI. Create a WinForms project, add a form, drag buttons from the toolbox.

Comment: @Blorgbeard There are legitimate reasons for adding controls using code behind, such as dynamically generated content.  It's a good skill to have, but the op needs to understand the limitations of doing it that way.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes. also your code does nothing with the position of button.

Comment: @NathanA yes, but it's hardly a skill, and there's no need most of the time. So why start that way?

Comment: `Application.Run(new Exercise());` was posted in the tutorial you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `Exercise` class and run that.

```
Application.Run(new Exercise());
```

Comment: I think the form appears, but not the button

Comment: @PhilippeParé it won't appear with OP's code. An instance of it is never created.

Comment: @Blorgbeard unless Application is a class defined by his teacher that opens the form and does the usual stuff, like enabling text rendering compatibility and such.

Comment: No, pretty sure it's the standard System.Windows.Forms.Application class.

Comment: Considering the using statements at the top, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

1) Controls created at runtime do not show up in the designer simply because they do not exist at that moment (they are created later, when running the application).

2) You need to create an instance of that form class and run it so it can get a message loop going to provide the much needed events.

3) Creating a control and adding it is not enough. You also have to set some visual properties, like position, size, caption.

Comment: regarding 3): it (at least a Button) has default values and will show up

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the graphical designer for designing interfaces.

If you really want to make the ui in code, you need to specify all the size, position and other important attributes.

If that's what you want, I recommend your try creating an empty windows form project, use the graphical interface and look at what's in the designer file. you'll see all the values the designer uses to display the control correctly.

Answer (score -3):

This is also referred to as dynamically creating a control. After declaring the variable and allocating memory for it, the control is available but doesn't have a host, which makes it invisible. A control must be positioned on a host like a form. The Form class itself contains a member variable named Controls. This member holds a list of the objects that are placed on the form. To specify that a control you have instantiated must be positioned on a form, the Controls member has a method named Add. Therefore, to make an object part of the form, pass its variable to the Add() method. Here is an example:

Read carefully the link you posted ,and copy and paste the next example .

Comment: Did you see the line  `Controls.Add(btnSubmit);`? OP exactly did what you said...

Comment: using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace prova1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
            
                Button newButton = new Button();
                buttons.Add(newButton);
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);
            
            
        }

      
    }
    
}

Comment: this should create as many buttons you need,i'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Er, no. It will just create a rather unused list `buttons` and only add one button, which is `newButton`.